# How to force libav to update duration for a growing file?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I have a video player in C who read files on local and distant network.

All works fine except for growing files (EG: a tv show currently in recording mode).

Is there a way to force the current context to update duration ? A flag in AVFormatContext ?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Posting a code exemple would not help, as it's the normal behaviour of libav functionality. It get the duration at init phase, with the avformat_find_stream_info function, but don't update the duration anymore after.